# ipython not working in org mode

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, ipython, install

I've followed everything [here](https://github.com/gregsexton/ob-ipython) in order to set up ipython in org mode. But I keep getting the error:

```
...executing Ipython code block...
apply: Searching for program: no such file or directory, ipython
```

when I try the sample code block

```
#+BEGIN_SRC ipython :session myip
  %matplotlib inline
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
#+END_SRC
```

Other samples don't work either. I've gotten ipython from Enthought, which should have all the necessities. Starting ipython from my (Ubuntu) terminal brings up:

```
Python 2.7.11 | 64-bit | (default, Jun 11 2016, 10:32:30) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
...
```

as it is on my path. I even installed `exec-path-from-shell` to make sure Emacs would see my path. Not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the python interpreter to ipython with:

```
(setq org-babel-python-command "ipython")
```

And then just use python with begin_src:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :session myip
  %matplotlib inline
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  import numpy as np
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: This didn't work either. I'm afraid it has something to do with my Enthought version of ipython.